# Installing ARCore application on an Android device

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

Trying to get the ARCore sample hello_ar_java running on an Xperia XA1 device. Seems to be going ok and it recognises that I need to install latest ARCore on the phone. All it gives me though is item not found and a retry button.

Anybody know what I'm missing?

I have "implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.0.0'" in the dependencies, use of the feature in the manifest and I believe there to be a configuration file for the XA1 too so I'm under the impression it's a supported device.

Only been poking at Android apps for about a week. My money is on something really nooby!

Any ideas?

Comment: Supported Devices section:
https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/

Comment: Thanks. That'd be a no then!

Answer (score 0):

Sony Xperia XA1 ***has no hardware gyroscope*** what is unacceptable when using ARCore. Instead of a real one, Xperia XA1 has a virtual gyroscope. So, it'll never be on the list of supported devices, and if so, you can't install ARCore app on it.

Check [this thread](https://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Xperia-XA1/Gyroscope-in-XA1/td-p/1225281#gref) on a forum.